# Can I calc sum with help of window function?

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

I can found total via query:

```
with sub_total as (
select 
 *,
 sum( qty*price ) OVER( PARTITION BY invoice_id, group_id )      AS order_cost
from invoice
)

-- Here how I get is expected result:
select *,
  (SELECT sum(x) from (SELECT sum( DISTINCT order_cost ) AS x FROM sub_total sub_i GROUP BY invoice_id, group_id) t) as total_cost
from sub_total;
```

Is this possible to found `sum` of those four numbers via window function?

[image]

I suppose this should work, but unfortunately no:

```
sum( DISTINCT order_cost ) OVER ( PARTITION BY invoice_id, group_id ORDER BY group_id RANGE unbound preceeding and unbound following )
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=cf718c8e6b31e7d8460175bdd593a601)

Comment: I found solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67167595/4632019

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the problem, you need a column with total value.

```
SELECT *,
      qty*price,
      SUM(qty*price) OVER (),
      SUM(qty*price) OVER (PARTITION BY invoice_id ORDER BY group_id)
 FROM invoice
```

That will output this:

[image]

Comment: yep, but question is slightly different. I have updated the fiddle. Because of rounding I can not use `SUM(qty*price) OVER ()`. Thus I should sum only those four numbers.

Comment: Your query will not work if there will be more invoices. I also update filddle which adds second invoice.