# How to `sum( DISTINCT <column> ) OVER ()` using window function?

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I have next data:

[image]

Here I already calculated total for `conf_id`. But want also calculate total for whole partition. eg:
**Calculate total suma by agreement for each its order (not goods at order which are with slightly different rounding)**

How to sum `737.38` and `1238.3`? eg. take only one number among group

(I can not sum( item_suma ), because it will return `1975.67`. Notice round for `conf_suma` as intermediate step)

**UPD**
Full query. Here I want to calculate rounded suma for each group. Then I need to calculate total suma for those groups

```
SELECT app_period( '2021-02-01', '2021-03-01' );


WITH
target_date AS ( SELECT '2021-02-01'::timestamptz ),
target_order as (
  SELECT
    tstzrange( '2021-01-01', '2021-02-01') as bill_range,
    o.*
  FROM ( SELECT * FROM "order_bt" WHERE sys_period @> sys_time() ) o
  WHERE FALSE
    OR o.agreement_id = 3385 and o.period_id = 10
),
USAGE AS ( SELECT
  ocd.*,


  o.agreement_id                  as agreement_id,
  o.id                            AS order_id,
  
  (dense_rank() over (PARTITION BY o.agreement_id       ORDER BY o.id                     )) as zzzz_id,
  (dense_rank() over (PARTITION BY o.agreement_id, o.id ORDER BY (ocd.ic).consumed_period )) as conf_id,

  
   sum( ocd.item_suma     ) OVER( PARTITION BY (ocd.o).agreement_id                 ) AS agreement_suma2,

 
  (sum( ocd.item_suma )  OVER( PARTITION BY (ocd.o).agreement_id, (ocd.o).id, (ocd.ic).consumed_period )) AS x_suma,
  (sum( ocd.item_cost )  OVER( PARTITION BY (ocd.o).agreement_id, (ocd.o).id, (ocd.ic).consumed_period )) AS x_cost,
  (sum( ocd.item_suma )  OVER( PARTITION BY (ocd.o).agreement_id, (ocd.o).id, (ocd.ic).consumed_period ))::numeric( 10, 2) AS conf_suma,
  (sum( ocd.item_cost )  OVER( PARTITION BY (ocd.o).agreement_id, (ocd.o).id, (ocd.ic).consumed_period ))::numeric( 10, 2) AS conf_cost,
  max((ocd.ic).consumed) OVER( PARTITION BY (ocd.o).agreement_id, (ocd.o).id, (ocd.ic).consumed_period )                   AS consumed,
  (sum( ocd.item_suma )  OVER( PARTITION BY (ocd.o).agreement_id, (ocd.o).id                           )) AS order_suma2
FROM target_order o
LEFT JOIN order_cost_details( o.bill_range ) ocd
  ON (ocd.o).id = o.id  AND  (ocd.ic).consumed_period && o.app_period
)

SELECT 
  *,
  (conf_suma/6) ::numeric( 10, 2 ) as group_nds,
  (SELECT sum(x) from (SELECT  sum( DISTINCT conf_suma )                       AS x FROM usage sub_u WHERE sub_u.agreement_id = usage.agreement_id GROUP BY agreement_id, order_id) t) as total_suma,
  (SELECT sum(x) from (SELECT (sum( DISTINCT conf_suma ) /6)::numeric( 10, 2 ) AS x FROM usage sub_u WHERE sub_u.agreement_id = usage.agreement_id GROUP BY agreement_id, order_id) t) as total_nds
FROM USAGE
WINDOW w AS ( PARTITION BY usage.agreement_id ROWS CURRENT ROW EXCLUDE TIES)
ORDER BY
  order_id,
  conf_id
```

My [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61293133/4632019)

Comment: Can you share the output you expect for this sample?

Comment: @Mureinik: One additional column with value `1975,68`

Comment: For all the rows? A single row? I'm not sure I'm following the logic here.

Comment: @eshirvana: added

Comment: please format your query , it's a mess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

better approach [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=01c699f3f47ca9fca8215f8cbf556218):

1. Assign `row_number` at each order: `row_number() over (partition by agreement_id, order_id ) as nrow`
2. Take only first suma: `filter nrow = 1`

````sql
with data as (
  select * from (values 
      ( 1, 1, 1, 1.0049 ), (2, 1,1,1.0049), ( 3, 1,1,1.0049 ) ,
      ( 4, 1, 2, 1.0049 ), (5, 1,2,1.0057), 
      ( 6, 2, 1, 1.53 ), ( 7,2,1,2.18), ( 8,2,2,3.48 )
 ) t (id, agreement_id, order_id, suma)
),
intermediate as (select 
 *,
 row_number() over (partition by agreement_id, order_id ) as nrow,
 (sum( suma ) over ( partition by agreement_id, order_id ))::numeric( 10, 2) as order_suma,
from data)

select 
  *,
  sum( order_suma ) filter (where nrow = 1) over (partition by agreement_id)
from intermediate```
````

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ad91c45a89270f60b443fb12e45221f9).

To run window function for distinct values I should get first value from each peer. To complete this I

1. `aggregate` IDs of rows for this peer
2. `lag` this aggregation by one
3. Mark rows that are not aggregated yet (this is first row at peer) as `_distinct`
4. sum(  ) FILTER ( WHERE _distinct ) over ( ... )

Voila. You get `sum` over DISTINCT values at target PARTITION
**which are not implemented yet by PostgreSQL**

```sql
with data as (
  select * from (values 
      ( 1, 1, 1, 1.0049 ), (2, 1,1,1.0049), ( 3, 1,1,1.0049 ) ,
      ( 4, 1, 2, 1.0049 ), (5, 1,2,1.0057), 
      ( 6, 2, 1, 1.53 ), ( 7,2,1,2.18), ( 8,2,2,3.48 )
 ) t (id, agreement_id, order_id, suma)
),
intermediate as (select 
 *,
 sum( suma ) over ( partition by agreement_id, order_id ) as fract_order_suma,
 sum( suma ) over ( partition by agreement_id           ) as fract_agreement_total,
 (sum( suma::numeric(10,2) ) over ( partition by agreement_id, order_id )) as wrong_order_suma,
 (sum( suma ) over ( partition by agreement_id, order_id ))::numeric( 10, 2) as order_suma,
 (sum( suma ) over ( partition by agreement_id           ))::numeric( 10, 2) as wrong_agreement_total,
 id as xid,
 array_agg( id ) over ( partition by agreement_id, order_id ) as agg
from data),

distinc as (select *,
  lag( agg ) over ( partition by agreement_id ) as prev, 
  id = any (lag( agg ) over ()) is not true as _distinct, -- allow to match first ID from next peer
  order_suma as xorder_suma, -- repeat column to easily visually compare with _distinct
  (SELECT sum(x) from (SELECT  sum( DISTINCT order_suma ) AS x FROM intermediate sub_q WHERE sub_q.agreement_id = intermediate.agreement_id GROUP BY agreement_id, order_id) t) as correct_total_suma
from intermediate
)
select 
*,
sum( order_suma ) filter ( where _distinct ) over ( partition by agreement_id ) as also_correct_total_suma
from distinc
```