# Why optimization is not applied/different index is used?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, query-planner

I have two pretty similar queries:

```sql
WITH USAGE AS NOT MATERIALIZED ( SELECT
  ocd.*,
  1 AS conf_suma
FROM(
        SELECT o, o.agreement_id AS agreement_id
        FROM "order_bt" o
        WHERE o.sys_period @> sys_time()
          AND  (o.app_period && tstzrange( '2021-01-01', '2021-02-01' ))
)ocd
)
SELECT 
  *,
  (conf_suma/6) ::numeric( 10, 2 ) as group_nds,
  (SELECT sum(conf_suma) from USAGE sq WHERE sq.agreement_id = agreement_id) as total_suma -- #1 SLOW
  -- #2 FAST: (SELECT sum(conf_suma) from USAGE sq WHERE sq.agreement_id = 3385) as total_suma
FROM USAGE
  WHERE agreement_id = 3385   -- LAST WHERE
```

They are differ only by this part `sq.agreement_id = agreement_id` VS `sq.agreement_id = 3385`

Plan for them are [#1 slow](https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/Lvt) and [#2 fast](https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/jmT)

#1 slow
[image]

#2 fast
[image]

Why optimization is not applied at first case? To my mind optimizer could see from `LAST WHERE` that there is only one `agreement_id`. So `agreement_id` is like constant. If we fold this constant into `slow` subquery it becomes same as `fast` subquery. Is this place for planner improvement?

PS. At one my query on production this cause query to run 12sec instead of 20ms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to **RhodiumToad** at IRC. Mistake was at `agreement_id` name.
It must be written as `usage.agreement_id`:

```
(SELECT sum(conf_suma) from USAGE sq WHERE sq.agreement_id = usage.agreement_id) as total_suma -- #1 NOW IT IS FAST TOO
```

Now [plan](https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/qLC) fine. As expected by me:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

because the slow query , aggregation function runs for all the rows that meet condition `sq.agreement_id = agreement_id` which is 1346 rows and then you filter the result of subquery
while the fast query you filter the result right off the bat and subquery only returns 4 rows thus only aggregation only runs for 4 rows.

also If you look at index condition for #4 Bitmap Index Scan , because of your condition sql optimizer has to look up these conditions :

```
((o_1.sys_period @> sys_time()) 
AND (o_1.app_period && '["2021-01-01 00:00:00+02","2021-02-01 00:00:00+02")'::tstzrange))
```

while in the fast query , index condition is

```
(o_1.agreement_id = 3385)
```

so those conditions in the slow query are postponed to `#3 Bitmap Heap Scan`  which only applies to 4 rows for fast query.

Comment: Yes, but it is easily noticeable that `sq.agreement_id = agreement_id` is equivalent to `sq.agreement_id = 3385`

Comment: so, why? it understand that `agreement_id` is constant and push its value down to `ocd` subquery, but does not do this for similar `total_suma` subquery.

Comment: because of second point in my answer , optimizer detects different conditions to look up the index and finding  o_1.agreement_id = 3385 is more distinct than the condition in the slow query

Comment: Is this place for improvement? When `LAST WHERE` makes `agreement_id` constant and when we fold this constant into subquery condition it becomes same as fast query.

Comment: to me looks like you can rewrite the query in a better way , if you provide sample data and desired output , it would be more clear

Comment: Here at the question sample data https://stackoverflow.com/q/67141374/4632019, at the answer there is [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ad91c45a89270f60b443fb12e45221f9) with desired output